# Get all userids in an active directory group using page control in an LDAP - Native api

Tags: c++, c, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am new to ldap programming. My aim is to to get the list of all the user ids from a particular group in Active Directory. I am implementing this using page control as the number of user's are large. I am doing this for Active Directory using the win32 LDAP library.

The following is the sequence,

1> Initialise: connect and bind 
2> Create your page control

```
ldap_create_page_control
```

3> Set the base, filter's and attributes

```
search base : CN=SSOGroup,CN=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=local)
CHAR *atribs[] = {"Department", "samAccountName", NULL};
char *filter = "(objectClass=user)";
```

4> Performed the search using, ldap_search_ext_s

5> Got the result and number of entries found.

**6>** used `ldap_get_dn` to get the DN

7> Check the cookie if there is another page, If yes go and do the same

8> Finalising steps

My question, **How can i get the user ids at step 6 instead of DNs?**

Will be helpful if you give me some pointers for me to investigate further.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because the title of your question is about the simple paged result control, but the story doesn't match the title?

Answer (score 0):

If you change search base to `CN=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=local` and use `(memberOf=CN=SSOGroup,CN=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=local)` as your search filter, you should get what you want.